# Confusion with attaching/detaching and different ObjectContext object

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, ado.net

I open a new `MessagesWindow` which has this code:

```
namespace Newsletter.UI
{
    public partial class MessagesWindow : Window
    {
        MessageService msgService;
        public MessagesWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            msgService = new MessageService();
        }

        private void CreateButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var createMessageWindow = new CreateMessageWindow { Owner = this };
            createMessageWindow.ShowDialog();
            gridMessages.ItemsSource = from msg in msgService.GetAllMessages()
                                       select msg;
        }

        private void messagesWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {          
            gridMessages.ItemsSource = from msg in msgService.GetAllMessages()
                                       select msg;
        }

        private void EditButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (gridMessages.SelectedItem == null)
                MessageBox.Show("You have to choose the message first.");
            else
            {
                var selectedMessage = (Message)gridMessages.SelectedItem;

                var editMessageWindow = new EditMessageWindow(selectedMessage);
                editMessageWindow.Owner = this;
                editMessageWindow.ShowDialog(); 
            }
            gridMessages.ItemsSource = from msg in msgService.GetAllMessages()
                                        select msg;
        }
    }
}
```

I open a new window with `EditButtonClick` where I want to edit my `Message`. The code of the `EditMessageWindow`:

```
namespace Newsletter.UI
{
    public partial class EditMessageWindow : Window
    {
        private Message editMessage;
        private MessageService messageService;
        public EditMessageWindow(Message message)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            editMessage = message;
            messageService = new MessageService();

        }

        private void CreateMessageWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            subject.Text = editMessage.Subject;
            messageContent.AppendText(editMessage.Content);
            senderComboBox.ItemsSource = messageService.GetAllSenders();

            mailingListComboBox.ItemsSource = messageService.GetAllMailingLists();

        }

        private void SaveClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            editMessage.Date = DateTime.Now;
            editMessage.Content = messageContent.Text;
            editMessage.MailingList.Add(messageService.GetAllMailingLists()[mailingListComboBox.SelectedIndex]); //ERROR
            editMessage.Sender = messageService.GetAllSenders()[senderComboBox.SelectedIndex];
            editMessage.Subject = subject.Text;
            editMessage.HasAttachments = false;
            messageService.EditMessage(editMessage);

            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error on `SaveClick`:

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because
>   they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

Finally, `MessageService` code:

```
namespace Newsletter.Services
{
    public class MessageService
    {
        private NewsletterEntities _context;

        public MessageService()
        {
            _context = new NewsletterEntities();
        }
        public void AddMessage(Message newMessage)
        {
            _context.Messages.AddObject(newMessage);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        public void EditMessage(Message editMessage)
        {
            var messageToChange = (from m in _context.Messages where editMessage.MessageID == m.MessageID select m).FirstOrDefault();
            if (messageToChange != null)
            {
                messageToChange = editMessage;
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public List<Message> GetAllMessages()
        {
            return (from m in _context.Messages select m).ToList();
        } 

        public List<MailingList> GetAllMailingLists()
        {
            var query = from m in _context.MailingLists select m;
            return query.ToList();
        }

        public List<Sender> GetAllSenders()
        {
            var query = from m in _context.Senders select m;
            return query.ToList();
        }

        public void DeleteMessage(Message message)
        {

            List<MailingList> mailingLists = new List<MailingList>();
            foreach(MailingList ml in message.MailingList.ToList())
            {
                ml.Message.Remove(message);
            }
            _context.Messages.DeleteObject(message);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting consfused with all those layers and contexts. I know I should probably somehow detach the message, do something with it and attach but I don't know where and how. Should I do it in the service layer in `MessageService`, UI layer, or maybe DAL layer where I have all my entities? Or should I redesign my solution and do the context logic in different place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you appear to have the setup of context per window. that will have 2 impacts on how you maintain the objects within the context.

1. You do not want to pass objects from form to form. instead you will pass the ID(s) from form to form and load the entity within the context.
2. As an entity is updated within one context you will need to notify the other windows/contexts of the change so they can refresh their data.

here is an MSDN article detailing the process of context per form. The article uses NHibernate, but the process would be almost identical for EF and DbCotext

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx